# How to count the time present in a given range in python

Tags: python, time

Assuming I have a time range of T1=15:00:00 - 23:00:00. And I have another time range, T2=20:00:00 -22:00:00. I want to know how many of the time in the range T2 is present in the time range T1. In my example, the result I'm expecting is 3 since all the time in the T2 is present in the time range.

Comment: Have you tried anything? People won't write your code for you. You should show some effort to solve the problem yourself, and then post here if you have a problem.

Comment: put the start time and end time in separate cells then do the minimum of t1&t2 end minus the maximum of t1&t2 start. Then add 1